# How to configure SSH keys on Windows for SourceTree, terminal and IDEs such as IntelliJ and Eclipse?

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

How does one configure SSH keys to work with SourceTree, the terminal and IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse on Windows?

This was driving me nuts for a while and I eventually came up with the following after a great deal of research and trial and error.  Thought I'd share here for future reference for myself and others.

Comment: This seems way too broad to me. You need to make some effort, like an attempt to solve the problem and associated error messages. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289).

Comment: Guess you didn't notice that I answered my own question? ;) I was "sharing my knowledge Q&A style" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All files are saved in C:\Users\windows-username\.ssh  (default .ssh location)

**Create SSH keys using PuTTYgen** (note: this is a separate utility to PuTTY)

Select key type from bottom (e.g. RSA, ED25519).  Click "generate" and follow on screen instructions to move mouse (makes key random).

You will now have a public and private key generated.  These now need to be saved.

**Save private key**

Save private key (will save as .ppk file).  This is so you can easily reload the key in the future and for use with SourceTree or any other utility that uses pageant.

**Export Open SSH key**

Also use Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key to produce a private key for use from terminal or an IDE.

**Create config file in .ssh folder**

Create a config file (file named `config` with no extension) in the .ssh folder that looks like this:

```
Host github.com
 Hostname github.com
 User github-user-1
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user-1-private-key

Host github.com
 Hostname github.com
 User github-user-2
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user-2-private-key

Host gitlab.com
 Hostname gitlab.com
 User gitlab-user
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab-user-private-key
```

The example above shows how you can have 2 GitHub users and 1 GitLab user at the same time.

**Add Public keys to relevant accounts**

You will need to add the public keys (copy & paste from PuTTYgen window) to your online accounts.  Look for documentation on how to do this online.

**Terminal and IDE Use**

You should now be able to use Git from the terminal or with IDE integration.  It will ask for the password for your private key.

**SourceTree Use**

To use in SourceTree, you will need to load up Pageant (loads in System Tray - small computer wearing a hat).  Right click -> Add key or open, add key.  Load the .ppk file and enter your private key password.

Comment: Where can one learn all this? I have been having an awful time getting sourcetree to switch between ssh keys for different accounts since github switched off the ability to use passwords. The token as a password wasn't authenticating either, most likely because of 2fa which I think I read somewhere. Anyway, I can see this info you have stated, especially about a config file being absolutely necessary in the future.

Comment: I had the same trouble trying to figure all this out and information on it was difficult to come by and spread out around the Internet.  Which is why I decided to create this Q&A as I figured (and hoped) people would come by it when searching online.  I can't actually remember where I got the information from and I've ended up using my own question as a reference.  And yes, the config file is key to using different accounts.

Answer (score 28):

(From the NavBar) Tools->options->general->SSH Client Configuration

Add the link to your private key on your drive.

Caution: I didn't use puTTY and instead used OpenSSH, so I had to change the SSH Client:

[image]